# Bind cannot load zone, checkzone says OK, checkconf disagrees, copied from known working zone

Tags: windows, domain-name-system, windows-server-2012-r2, linux-networking, bind

I have a BIND9 (9.9.10-P2) server running on Windows Server 2012 R2. I have 2 views - an internal and external - serving up two zones for domains I own.

For some reason, one of these zones it refuses to serve up answers for despite the server starting without complaints. When creating Zone 2 (the problem zone), since it is set up exactly like Zone 1, I simply copied the file from Zone 1 and replaced the relevant bits with the new name. Checkzone says it's ok and shows no errors. Running checkconf -z throws errors for Zone 2 but not Zone 1:

```
C:\Program Files\ISC BIND 9\bin>named-checkconf.exe -z ..\etc\named.conf
C:\Program Files\ISC BIND 9\etc\zones\domain2.net.int:4: ignoring out-of-zone data
 (domain2.net)
C:\Program Files\ISC BIND 9\etc\zones\domain2.net.int:16: ignoring out-of-zone dat
a (dns.domain2.net)
zone domain2.net/IN: has 0 SOA records
zone domain2.net/IN: has no NS records
zone domain2.net/IN: not loaded due to errors.
internal/domain2.net/IN: bad zone
zone domain1.net/IN: loaded serial 2
C:\Program Files\ISC BIND 9\etc\zones\domain2.net.ext:4: ignoring out-of-zone data
 (domain2.net)
C:\Program Files\ISC BIND 9\etc\zones\domain2.net.ext:16: ignoring out-of-zone dat
a (dns.domain2.net)
zone domain2.net/IN: has 0 SOA records
zone domain2.net/IN: has no NS records
zone domain2.net/IN: not loaded due to errors.
external/domain2.net/IN: bad zone
zone domain1.net/IN: loaded serial 2
```

Here is my named.conf:

```
key "rndc-key" {
    algorithm hmac-md5;
    secret "nah";
};

controls {
    inet 127.0.0.1 port 953
    allow { 127.0.0.1; } keys { "rndc-key"; };
};

acl internals {
    127.0.0.0/8;
    10.16.0.0/22;
};

view "internal" {
    match-clients { internals; };
    recursion yes;
    zone "domain2.net" {
        type master;
        file "C:\Program Files\ISC BIND 9\etc\zones\domain2.net.int";
    };
    zone "domain1.net" {
        type master;
        file "C:\Program Files\ISC BIND 9\etc\zones\domain1.net.int";
    };
};
view "external" {
    match-clients { any; };
    recursion no;
    zone "domain2.net" {
        type master;
        file "C:\Program Files\ISC BIND 9\etc\zones\domain2.net.ext";
    };
    zone "domain1.net" {
        type master;
        file "C:\Program Files\ISC BIND 9\etc\zones\domain1.net.ext";
    };
};
```

Here is Zone 1/Domain 1, the working one:

```
; domain1.net
$TTL 86400
$ORIGIN domain1.net.
domain1.net.        IN  SOA dns.domain1.net. hostmaster (
                2           ; Serial number
                10800           ; Refresh
                3600            ; Retry
                604800          ; Expire
                86400)          ; Minimum TTL

            ; Nameservers
            IN  NS  dns.domain1.net.
            IN  NS  dns.domain2.net.

; Records
dns.domain1.net.    IN  A   127.0.0.2
```

Here is Zone 2/Domain 2, the broken one:

```
; domain2.net
$TTL 86400
$ORIGIN domain2.net.
domain2.net.        IN  SOA dns.domain2.net. hostmaster (
                2           ; Serial number
                10800           ; Refresh
                3600            ; Retry
                604800          ; Expire
                86400)          ; Minimum TTL

            ; Nameservers
            IN  NS  dns.domain2.net.
            IN  NS  dns.domain1.net.

; Records
dns.domain2.net.    IN  A   127.0.0.6
```

As far as I can tell Zone 1/Domain 1 works perfectly fine. I have deleted and recreated and copied these files numerous times with no success.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's ignoring the records in the domain 2 zone files as "out of zone", which seems to indicate a mismatch between the `zone "domain2.net" {` line of the conf and the `domain2.net.` name in your zone file, which might have been lost in your domain obfuscation.

Do those two strings match *exactly* between those two files (apart from the trailing dot in the zone file), and are there any special characters or encoding differences?

Comment: `named-checkzone -o - domain2.net domain2.net.zonefile`  will dump the zonefile with the $ORIGIN and related macros expanded.  You've got something mismatched in obfuscation since your error reports a zone file path ( internal/domain2... ) that shouldn't appear.

Comment: You guys were right. Despite checking it 30 or 40 times I just totally missed it - rookie mistake with letters that are similar. It really is nice to have someone else's eyes on it to get you to really, _really_ make sure you entered it right. Thanks guys, have a nice day.